# Determine if text from string will be wrapped or not

Tags: c#, string, word-wrap

I have big multiline(containing \r\n) indented string which content is some source code.
And I have informations about TextBox in which this code was written (size of textbox, font type, font size etc.)

How can I simulate/ determine where particular pieces of this string was in such TextBox?

For Example, line 12 of this string looks like this (note that at the beginning there are 3 tab indent.):

```
12:            Console.WriteLine("Please write a whole number to which you want to print all powers of two.");
```

But in a TextBox in which this code was written was only 454 pixels wide and had no horizontal scrollbar so this line looked like this (of course while it is still line 12 there shouldn't be line numbers 13 and 14 - just for better imagination):

```
12:            Console.WriteLine("Please write a whole 
13: number to which you want to print all powers of 
14: two.");
```

So now for example I want to know that `two.");` was on line 14 column 0-7 so I can compute it in pixels for example from X=455,Y=0 to X=467,Y=70, when I have additional information about font (font type, size, width of particular letters).

Comment: dare I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx not help?

Comment: @ADyson working with eyetracking and I want to know where particular parts of text on the screen were. So then I can work with text as a visual stimulus which is much better than working with picture where you don't know what is a content.

Comment: @BugFinder that looks great I will check it and will thought how to use it. Hope it will lead me to solution :)

Comment: @Gondil ok I see. I thought it was going to be some hack to try and display the text in the same way at a later point. But yours seems like a reasonable requirement. Bugfinder's suggestion looks good - I didn't know about that either!

Comment: @ADyson good to know that there are users who care about purpose on which OP want to use solution :)

Comment: In fairness I havent used it in c# i used it in delphi when I was writing stuff to wrap lines.. :)

Comment: I'll see if it will help me :) But it looks good.

Comment: @Gondil I care because sometimes there is a better way to achieve it. Or sometimes it's the X-Y problem - it's a workaround to the real problem, and it would be easier t solve that underlying issue or misunderstanding. Good luck solving this one, it's intriguing. Sorry I can't offer any specific advice.

Comment: Still haven't figured out what Graphics I should use for calling this method. For now I always get result from method as Width 0, IsEmpty true, Height 0 :(